# Remove single element from 2D Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code for a 2D array:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;  

const int CITY = 2;
const int DAYS = 3;

int main()
{
    int temperature [CITY][DAYS];
    int value, rowPosition, columnPosition;

    // Insertion
    for (int i = 0; i < CITY; i++)
    {
         for(int j = 0; j < DAYS; j++)
         {
             cout << "City " << i + 1 << ", Day " << j + 1 << " : ";
             cin >> temperature[i][j];
         }
    }  

    // Deletion
    cout << "Enter row-position to delete: ";
    cin  >> rowPosition;

    cout << "Enter column-position to delete: ";
    cin  >> columnPosition;

    for (int i = rowPosition; i < CITY; i++)
    {
        for(int j = columnPosition; j < DAYS; j++)
        {
           temperature[rowPosition][columnPosition] = temperature[rowPosition + 1][columnPosition + 1];
        }
    }  

    // Search
    cout << "Enter value to search: ";
    cin  >> value;

    for (int i = 0; i < CITY; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < DAYS; j++)
        {
            if(value == temperature[i][j])
            {   
                cout << "The value " << value << " is found at index " << i + 1 << " " << j + 1 << endl;
            }
        }
    }  

    // Display
    for (int i = 0; i < CITY; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < DAYS; j++)
        {
            cout << "City " << i + 1 << ", Day " << j + 1 << " = " << temperature[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }  
return 0;  
}
```

For instance, `CITY = 2` and `DAYS = 3`, means the 2D array will compose of 2 rows and three columns. Now I want to remove a single element from this 2D array, say the element at position `row = 2`, `col = 1`.

I tried the above-mentioned deletion code but it displays again the same array without removing.

Comment: Show a complete example.  We don't know the scope of temperature. Plus it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Be more specific about what you expect your program to do.

Comment: What do you mean with `remove element`? Arrays are fixed-size containers. Then you should use a `std::vector`. Also be aware that invalid indexes are `0 through n - 1`. If you have 2 rows and you write `array[2]` then it is incorrect.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::array` and/or `std::vector`?

Comment: @Raindrop7 but you can remove (overwrite) the values in an array for instance just move each 1 index backward, the initial value will be removed

Comment: But what about if the index is in the middle?

Comment: @Raindrop7 I tried just moving 1 index backwards in 1-D array case, I succeeded. Now I want the same in 2-D case

Comment: Get away from moving indexes but just create another array copying all the elements of the original array excluding the value to be deleted

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between a `one-dim array` and multiple dimension array? Then you  can solve it.

Comment: Yeah I know, the code is depicting that

Comment: @JesperJuhl: The op may not achieve what he wants "remove" using an array or vector but maybe an `std::list` where  he can delete or insert in anywhere in the list.

Comment: @Raindrop7 anything you can do with a `list` you can do with a `vector`. And regardless of `list`s theoretical big O advantage when inserting or removing elements, a `vector` usually turns out to be faster on modern hardware due to not having to chase pointers all over memory and the `vector` being more friendly to the prefetcher. In most cases (in my experience), a `list` is just about the *worst* datastructure you can pick, for any problem. `vector` *always* beats it in practice - even where it seems it should not.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: How to inset at the middle of a vector for example? No I don't think so. Lists are more effective at inserting deleting from anywhere but the overhead is walking an element in the list you should start from the head. Whereas A vector cannot insert at the beginning or or the middle but it is effective when reading values at random indexes.

Comment: @Raindrop7 - easy; just use [std::vector::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert). And yes, that may cause memory allocation  and copying of elements. But modern CPUs are *really good* at that sort of thing for stuff that's laid our linearly in memory, so in the end it usually still ends up being faster than `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the '#' for `#include`

I see what you are trying to do, not actually deleting anything but moving everything to the "deleting" indices?
Note: this is not a nested for loop.
This is what I would do instead

```
temperature[rowPosition][columnPosition] = 0;       // in case at the end of array
for (int i = columnPosition; i < DAYS-1; i++)
    temperature[rowPosition][i] = temperature[rowPosition][i + 1]; // move all back
```

Comment: Still not succeeded

Comment: I edited it and It should work now. I have compiled it and works for me.

Comment: But not working for me, it is again displaying the same values in 2-D array